# php regular expression for extracting a phone number

Tags: php

I need help with php regular expression.
I have a $text variable.
For example:"*foo foo random words* Caller Phone:+922432202229 *random words foo words*"
I want to extract 922432202229 from $text.
**Please Note that the $text could contains other similar numbers too,so I just want the number which comes right after  "*Caller Phone :*"**
Here is what I tried:

```
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/Caller Phone : +[0-9]{12}$/", $text, $matches);
    $matches = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Is it "Caller Phone :" or "Caller Phone:"? (that is, is there a space before the colon?) Also, does the plus sign (`+`) neccessarily occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be more flexible and safe:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/Caller Phone\s*:\s*\(+|)([0-9]{8,12})/i', $text, $matches);
$phones = $matches[2];
```

Comment: That worked! Is there a way to get only the number? I mean I'm getting "Caller Phone:922432202229",I just want this "922432202229".

Comment: see my edit, that should do the trick, use `$matches[1]`, also: are you sure your phone numbers are always 12 numbers with a `+` directly infront of them? because those are the only ones that will get matched like this

Comment: Didn't think about that,is there something like {12 or 8} or something else for numbers with number of digits ranging between 8 to 12?

Comment: i edited my post, use `$matches[2]`now, the plus is optional and the numbers have to 8 to 12 digits

Answer (score 1):

You will need to collect the actual value behind `Phone:` by using the `()`, like so:

`preg_match_all("/Caller Phone : ([0-9]+)$/", $text, $matches);`

I also changed `{12}` to `+` so you also have all numbers as long as it will go on. Validation must go afterwards then.

Only by using `()` you will have values be returned to your `$matches` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/Caller Phone:\+\d{12}/i", $text, $matches);
    $matches = $matches[0];
```

If you have this data in `$text` variable

$text = "foo foo random words Caller Phone:+922432202229 random words foo words";

It will show this result on the your given data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Caller Phone:+922432202229
    )

)
```